# gulp babel 6.14.0 not working

Tags: gulp, babeljs

It sure feels like I am following all the advise for using `gulp` with `babel ^6`.

I have done:

#### Gulp

- `npm i -g gulp-cli`
  I also have:
- `npm i -D gulp-cli`
- `npm i -D gulp`

`gulp -v` gives:

```
> gulp -v
[12:43:00] Failed to load external module babel-register
[12:43:00] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[12:43:00] CLI version 3.9.1
[12:43:00] Local version 3.9.1
```

#### Babel

My **package.json** has:

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-core": "^6.14.0",
"babel-preset-es2016": "^6.11.3",
```

and for good measure also:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2016"
    ]
  },
```

My **.babelrc** has

```
{
  "presets": ["es2016"]
}
```

#### npm

Then, to ensure its all going to work, I delete **./node_modules**`and run`npm install`.

My **gulpfile.bable.js** begins:

```
`use strict` 

import gulp from 'gulp'
```

The output from `gulp` begins:

```
here\>gulp
[12:42:51] Failed to load external module babel-register
[12:42:51] Requiring external module babel-core/register
here\gulpfile.babel.js:3
import gulp from 'gulp';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Comment: `babel-preset-es2016` is just the new stuff in `es2016`, so it doesn't include module syntax, you'll want both `es2015` and `es2016`.

Comment: omg, thank you! that seems like a bug

Comment: @loganfsmyth - I'd mark it as the answer if you'd be so kind as to post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config `"presets": ["es2016"]` only tells Babel to compile ES2016 -> ES2015. If you need to cover ES2015 -> ES5 (to convert ES2015 module syntax), you'd want `"presets": ["es2015", "es2016"]` to cover both cases.